# Export To excel in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0

I have  button on my page  for" Export To Excel". The ButtonClick function is  to export the datgrid (dgrISGrid) to excel Code is attached below:
But while executing its throwing error as"thread is aborted".Whats the solution?

```
    protected void imgbtnExport_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
      try
      {

        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=InformationSystems.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
        System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
        dgrISGrid.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
        Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
        Response.End();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {

        ExceptionHandler ObjExceptionHandler = new ExceptionHandler();
        lblError.Text = ObjExceptionHandler.GetExceptionDetails(ex);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response.End() causes this error.

Try using "Response.Flush()" just before this statement.

Comment: I tried it .Actually the messgaebox pop up comes asking to open or save.. After that the error comes.. saying the text inside is correpted.

Actually my application has other export to excels also.. None of them is working.Is it the problem of excel version i have>? it is microsoft office excel 2007 on my pc